# SQL: How to use GROUP BY and ORDER BY together in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am fetching seat bookings from my database and wanted to fetch the lastest entry and group it them with patient_reg_no here is my code,

```
SELECT * 
FROM seat_booking 
WHERE patient_reg_no like '" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%' and is_active = 'Y' 
GROUP BY patient_reg_no 
ORDER BY booking_id DESC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on this? What are the columns you need? Do you want to retrieve latest entry for each customer?

Comment: When you use a `GROUP BY` you should also use an aggregate function for every column you select which is not part of the `GROUP BY` statement. See for example https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx

Comment: What is your question? Problem? Error or undesired results? Please [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70317330/edit) with details.

Comment: Like what? @Parfait

Comment: You are asking a question in the title with an attempted query in the body that does what the question asks. What is the issue you are facing? Please edit post (not in comments) with details.

Comment: @h.m.i.13 please give code with the use of aggregate_function()

Comment: @Samey please give table structure. Additionally an example of the content of the table and the expected result would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have chosen to use a wildcard character to select your columns:  *.  The database doesn't know which columns to group by because you have selected all columns.  I have added a table alias to assign the domain of the column names.  This will help greatly if you should decide to JOIN another table.

```
SELECT sb.patient_reg_no, sb.booking_id
FROM seat_booking sb
WHERE sb.patient_reg_no like '" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%' and sb.is_active = 'Y' 
GROUP BY sb.patient_reg_no
ORDER BY sb.booking_id DESC;
-- LIMIT 20;  -- Remove the limit until the results are correct
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
select patient_reg_no ,booking_id 
from
(SELECT patient_reg_no , booking_id 
,rank() over (partiotion by patient_reg_no  order by booking_id  desc) rank
FROM seat_booking 
WHERE patient_reg_no like '" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%' and is_active = 'Y' 
)a
where rank=1
```